# Relation between the columns of a Jordan form and its change of basis matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Given the following matrix:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 4 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
We find its eigenvalues, and eigenvectors:
$$
|A - \lambda \mathbb{I}| = (3 - \lambda)^3 = 0
$$
We get the eigenvalue: $\lambda = 3$, with geometrical multiplicity $k = 3$.
$$
\dim(\ker(A - 3 \mathbb I)) = 2 \\ \; \\
\ker(A - 3 \mathbb I) = \text{span} \left \{  \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\right \}
$$
So the matrix is not diagonalizable. So we try to find its Jordan normal form. But I have some doubts.
First, how would you know that the Jordan form is like:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
or like this:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 3 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
how can I know?

And, how would I find the change of basis matrix $P$? I've tried with:
$$
(A - 3 \mathbb{I})^2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \\ \; \\\
\ker(A - 3 \mathbb{I})^2 = \mathbb{R}^3  = \text{span} \left \{  \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\right \}
$$
Would this three last vectors be the columns of the matrix $P$?

Could someone explain me this in depth, and how would you relate this vectors with the Jordan form (in a similar way, you can relate the vectors of a diagonal matrix with the basis of its eigenspace).

Answer (score 0):

Both of the matrices that you mentioned are Jordan normal forms of $A$.

Let $v_1=(1,0,0)$ and let $v_2=(0,1,1)$. Then $A.v_1=3v_1$ and $A.v_2=3v_2$. Besides, if $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3$, then$$A.(x,y,z)-3(x,y,z)=(0,y-z,y-z).$$Clearly, if you take, say $y=1$ and $z=0$, then $A.(x,y,z)-3(x,y,z)=(0,1,1)=v_2$. So, let $v_3=(0,1,0)$. Then $A.v_3=3v_3+v_2$, and therefore, if you take$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$(the columns of $P$ are $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$), then$$P^{-1}.A.P=\begin{bmatrix}3&0&0\\0&3&1\\0&0&3\end{bmatrix}.$$